# How get coords from click event in X°Y′Z" format (not in X.Y == decimal)

Tags: javascript, maps, yandex-api, yandex-maps

`e.get('coords')` from code below, returns coords in decimal format, but I need them in X°Y′Z" format. Is there any way to get this without manual converting?

```
myMap.events.add('click', setCoords);

function setCoords(e) {
    var coords = e.get('coords');

     $('#id_lat').val(coords[0]);
     $('#id_lon').val(coords[1]);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try function like this:

```
function format(coords) {
  var deg = parseInt(coords);
  var min = parseInt((60 * coords) % 60);
  var sec = (60*60 * coords) % 60;
  return deg+'deg'+min+"'"+sec+'"';
}
```

Comment: thanks, but `without manual converting?`. In their api docs I've found only one reference to coordinate formats - that `geocoder` recognise `+-deg° mm' ss", +-deg° mm' ss"` but looks like returns only in decimal format. https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/doc/geocoder/desc/concepts/input_params-docpage/

Comment: from http://help.yandex.ru/ "Поясните, пожалуйста, подробнее, что Вы имеете в виду." xD ... ok I'll accept this answer, but I think that ability of representation in multiple formats should be implemented in api.

Comment: go to yandex guys with your feature request :) I can't to implement it in their API